# controversial question

Tags: discussion, answers, questions

[A fraud in the terms of use](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/46745/a-fraud-in-the-terms-of-use)

There are completely different answers, some said it **was** a fraud, while some said it was **not**.

How may I deal with that? I need some help.