# What's the point of a locked post with no feedback?

Tags: discussion, questions, comments

While scrolling through meta I came across [this question](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/945/controversial-question) that is locked but has no feedback (answer/comments). It seemed pretty odd and without reason.

I tried digging into the history of this post and it seems pretty clean, other than a little heated back and forth between two users on the linked post, which is pretty normal (we are a site about the law).

This is more or less curiosity about why it was locked, it doesn't seem to fit the standards of when posts should be locked. Then again I could just be lacking the background to events that led up to it being locked.

Comment: I think this is a case of "improvements" in the SE engine: things don't behave the way you expect in the current version.

Answer (score 1):

The question was migrated from the [meta](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/945/controversial-question) to the [main site](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/46814/how-to-reconcile-opposing-legal-answers) because it is a question of legal interpretation and fits better there than here.

I can see this clearly:

[image: screenshot]

What can you see?

Comment: the blue box didn't appear when I first view the question but after refreshing the page it appeared. So that's why I deleted this question.

Comment: @User37849012643 it's still a good question so I undeleted it.